# How to be able to select file when using React Native Web?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

We are building an app that’s using react native but we are not releasing a native version for the first release. We are still using web (using `react-native-web` for this).

However, I am stuck with file upload functionality because to use a react native component, we need to be doing native permissions (but we are not deploying it natively so there’s no such thing in browsers). But at the same time, I am not able to use a simple `<input type=“file” />` since the UI is built on react native-specific tags (e.g. `<View>` / `<Image>`, etc.)

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a suggestion that would work for you!

seeing that in react-native-web you can specify platform specific files, if you can create a separate upload file component something like 
`'fileUploader.web.js'` 
and you can combine that with this package 
https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone

```
<Dropzone ref="_dp" onDrop={uploadPhotos}>
    <Text>TEXT HERE</Text> // you can remove this completely
</Dropzone>
```

you can actually style the dropzone to be completely invisible and trigger file picker with :

```
this.refs._dp.open()
```

Keep in mind this only handles the web platform, you will need to create a `fileUploader` for the other platforms

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried using `<input />` between `<View> </View>`? this should work:

```
<View>
   <input type="file" onChange={fileSelectedHandler} accept="image/*" />
 </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no compatible control in react-native-web. you can develop using

https://github.com/kamilkp/react-native-file-transfer

https://github.com/g6ling/React-Native-Tips/tree/master/How_to_upload_photo%2Cfile_in%20react-native